# Is it possible to mark the same tag as "Interesting" and "Ignored"?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, tag-watching, ignored-tags

Can you mark the same tag as both *interesting* and *ignored*? If you can, what is the resulting appearance of a question with that tag?

Answer (score 6):

You can. If this is done and you have "hide ignored" checked in your preferences, tags with a tag you are both favoriting and ignoring will be hidden. If "hide ignored" is not checked, they will be both highlighted and faded (in the colors as appropriate for the site you are on). These are the same behaviors that are seen on a post where one tag is favorited and another is ignored.

Highlighting, fading and hiding of questions is all done client-side and the routine for each is ignorant of the others. I believe this is how the behavior should work. It is the responsibility of the end user to appropriately select and manage their `interesting` and `ignored` tags.